# wpf best way to implement win explorer new folder UI

Tags: wpf, explorer

I'm trying to implement a UI like Win7 explorer. For example if you are clicking on New Folder button the new line With name "New Folder" is adding in explorer ListView and the name is staying selected to let you change with new one.

So what is the best way to implement it in WPF?

thanks

Comment: `Best way to implement WPF UI?` - XAML and MVVM... What have you tried??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your xaml, in the data template, you might have a TextBlock and TextBox overlapped, and in normal view, make

```
TextBox.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
TextBlock.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
```

Toggle this when you wish to have an inline edit on the file names.

```
TextBox.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
TextBlock.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
           Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Visibility="{Binding CaptionEditBoxVisibility, 
           Converter= {StaticResource InvertVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox x:Name="FolderNodeEdit"
           Text="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWay}"
           Visibility="{Binding CaptionEditBoxVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The InvertVisibility converter is to convert from visible to collapsed or vice versa.